# How to replace <key, value> in a std multimap

Tags: c++, multimap

Rehrasing the question - 
Question rephrased - 
I have a requirement where I need to replace a  pair with a new key and value. Consider this -

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string> mymap;

    mymap.insert(std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(0, "A1"));
    mymap.insert(std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(0, "A2"));
    mymap.insert(std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(2, "C1"));
    mymap.insert(std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(2, "C2"));
    mymap.insert(std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(1, "B1"));
    mymap.insert(std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(1, "B2"));
    mymap.insert(std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(1, "B3"));

    std::pair<std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::iterator, std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::iterator> pr = mymap.equal_range(1);

    std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::iterator it;
    for (it=pr.first; it!=pr.second; ++it)
    {
        unsigned int key = it->first;
    key = key+10;

        std::string val = it->second;
        val = "X" + val;
        mymap.erase(it);
        mymap.insert(std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(key, val));

    }

    for ( it=mymap.begin() ; it != mymap.end(); it++ )
    {
        cout << (*it).first << " => " << (*it).second << endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The program crashes on visual studio 2008 since the iterator is invalidated.

I expect it to be:

```
0 => A1
0 => A2
2 => C1
2 => C2
11 => XB1
11 => XB2
11 => XB3
```

The idea is I want to replace an existing entry in the map with a new entry.

What am I doing wrong? Any help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick is to advance the iterator first, then erase a copy of the iterator.

```
std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::iterator it = pr.first;
while (it != pr.second)
{
    unsigned int key = it->first;
    key = key+10;

    std::string val = it->second;
    val = "X" + val;

    std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::iterator itCopy = it;
    ++it;
    mymap.erase(itCopy);
    mymap.insert(std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(key, val));
}
```

In C++11, you can do this:

```
std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::iterator it = pr.first;
while (it != pr.second)
{
    unsigned int key = it->first;
    key = key+10;

    std::string val = it->second;
    val = "X" + val;

    it = mymap.erase(it);
    mymap.insert(std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(key, val));
}
```

By the way, because this code is increasing the key each time, it will process every element over and over again.

Comment: Many Many Thanks! This technique worked for this problem as well as my bigger problem.

Comment: I added the line key = key +10 because I wanted to demonstrate that my new key is based upon the old key. In fact the new key is obtained by looking up old key in a different data structure.

Comment: I also want to add that starting with C++11, you can simplify the insert to mymap.insert( {key, val} ); (using aggregate initialization).

Answer (score 2):

If you erase the entry where the iterator is, all links to the rest of the multimap are potentially lost.

(new) solution:

Simply do the "erase" after you inserted the new entries:

```
std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::iterator it;
for (it=pr.first; it!=pr.second; ++it)
{
    unsigned int key = it->first;
    key = key+10;

    std::string val = it->second;
    val = "X" + val;
    mymap.insert(std::multimap<unsigned int, std::string>::value_type(key, val));
}
mymap.erase(pr.first, pr.second);
```

Comment: Oh wait, in process of simplifying my bigger problem I seem to have asked given wrong example. I'll edit my question a bit...

Comment: I tried the above. It works for changing the value, but in my case I need to change the key as well.

Comment: Now I got hands on a compiler and fixed my answer. Simply do the "erase" after you inserted the new entries to the multimap.

Comment: Thank you. This solution also worked to solve my original problem. I'll have to now weigh out between this and the solution above.